# Is there a way to take screenshot from a window that is not currently active through a Python script?

Tags: python, windows, screenshot

I have seen ways to take screenshots easily for the active window in Windows OS.

I would like to know if there is a way and how to take screenshots from windows that are minimized in Windows OS, through a Python script.

The reason is because I am building a bot app for a game that will run for multiple clients and it works massively based in screenshots and reading numbers and words from screenshots, but I'm not having luck by getting a working solution for the screenshot part. I even tried chat gpt and bard but apparently there is some sort of protection from Windows itself.

Comment: Game bots have been sued in the past, with success, due to causing damages to the company, and are considered illegal in some countries. SO ToS doesn't allow promoting illegal activity. It seems to be an open conversation, but this question -may- not be recommended : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged

Comment: @SébastienVercammen: Google, Microsoft, Amazon and Apple have also been sued in the past, with success, and some of their products are considered illegal in some countries; and it's still OK to ask and answer questions about their products on StackOverflow. The question itself doesn't indicate that OP is doing (intentionally are accidentally) anything against any ToS or law. For example, ToS of some games disallows bots only in multiplayer mode.

Comment: @pts OP asked about multiple clients, I did assume that increased the odds of it being a multiplayer game. I linked to the conversation because it's relevant, not to end it - that's up to you.